# How to use selectedItemsLabel correctly with PrimeNg MultiSelect

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using MultiSelect component from PrimeNg. I want to use a property `selectedItemsLabel`. This property is used to set the text to "1 item selected", "2 items selected" and so on as you keep on selecting. I want to put some custom text there. Here is my code:

```
<p-multiSelect ... [selectedItemsLabel]="selectedItemsLabel"></p-multiSelect>
```

Here is the logic:

```
selectedItemsLabel;     
onSelectingItem() {
  this.selectedItemsLabel="Hello world";
}
```

But then the dropdown text becomes blank. Am I not using it correctly? Please point out my mistake.

Comment: You seem to be making assumptions about how the component works. Maybe you should read the [docs](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect) for it.

Comment: Thanks for the info Richards. But I've read the documentation properly. The only difference is that instead of assigning a sting there at the template i'm just trying to assign it through my logic.

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz please?